# App too big? Crashlytics: Archive Distribution Error: -3 (413)

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I've trying to upload a new version of my iOS app to Beta (Crashlytics) from the fabric app on my Mac but I'm getting the next error:

```
Crashlytics: Archive Distribution Error: -3

Could not upload the distribution. The operation couldn't be completed. (HTTP error 413.)
```

HTTP error 413 says that the request entity is too large. My app has a size of 1.6 GB. Anyone knows which is the max size that we can upload to Beta?

Is there any way to upload big apps without getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todd from Fabric here. The limit is determined by connection speed as well as a hard limit we do not publicly disclose. We recommend you stay under 400MB. As is, your app is well above our maximum limit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!